# CSS: Distribute non-table elements in table-like manner

Tags: html, css

Having a div containing dynamically generated `<span>`s is it possible to display them in a table-like manner AND decide which  goes to which column of the table? This is what I have:

```html
<div>
<span class="left">LEFT1</span>
<span class="right">RIGHT1</span>
<span class="left">LEFT2</span>
<span class="center">CENTER1</span>
</div>
```

this is what I want to achieve (I don't mean the code but the visualization so please run the snippet):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>LEFT1</td>
    <td>CENTER1</td>
    <td>RIGHT1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LEFT2</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Unfortunately I don't have the possibility to have table generated or change the order of `<span>`s.

Comment: The CSS table model requires your HTML to adhere to the same structure as HTML tables, so you won't be able to use that.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't do this unless there is no other option just change your markup!

If you for some unknown reason do have to *absolutely* use this.
Here is css that will center the `.center` class.
Put the `.right` on the right.
and put the second left on a new line.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 2em;
}
.center {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
.left:nth-of-type(3) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="left">LEFT1</span>
  <span class="right">RIGHT1</span>
  <span class="left">LEFT2</span>
  <span class="center">CENTER1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I have more items? As I mentioned, it's generated dynamically, two 'lefts' were just an example. There could be more items of each class.

Comment: What you ask for is really hard to achieve and generally shouldn't be done at all. Markup and style is like a couple, if you don't cooperate it will not be a long relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This still would need a lot more coding:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnr9pnLo/2/)

```
span {
border:1px solid gray;
display:block;
width:60px;
}
.right {
float:right;
position:relative;
}
.center {
position:relative;
left:40%;
}
.right + .right {
float:right;
right:8px;
margin-top:18px;
position:absolute;
}
```

You'd need another varies of selectors like `.center:first-of-type` for every item which has space above. But it's not impossible! Still kinda hard-coded :)

Answer (score 0):

As Persijn mentions, markup and style go hand in hand so what you are after is awkward. That said, the ability to change element order does exist in CSS if you use `flexbox`:

- Set `div` to `display: wrap;` to instruct its children to use the `flexbox` model
- Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `div` to allow the children to wrap onto a new line
- Set `flex: 0 0 33.333333%;` on `div span`. This will tell the `span`s to take up a third of the width of the `div`
- Set `order: n;` on the different `span` elements to get the desired order

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div span {
  flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
}
.left {
  order:1;
}
.center {
  order:2;
}
.right {
  order:3;
}
.left ~ .left {
  order:4;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="left">LEFT1</span>
  <span class="right">RIGHT1</span>
  <span class="left">LEFT2</span>
  <span class="center">CENTER1</span>
</div>
```

Just be aware that depending on the number of `span`s you need to deal with the CSS for this method could become quite bloated and unwieldy.